# Iterate through zero in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can I construct a for loop so that I iterate form zero to 15 in increments of 4, starting with zero? In other words, output should be 0,3,7,11,15

Comment: Zero to three is three, not four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
for( i=0; i<16; i+=i==0?3:4) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please explain this?

Comment: @jamesson If you will add parenthesis,you will understand the logic-> `i+=((i==0)?3:4)`

Comment: So; Add to I 3 if it equals zero, otherwise add 4?

Comment: @jamesson - It basically says to only increment by 4 if `i` is not `0`. If `i` is `0`, it'll only increment by `3`.

Comment: Yea just beat me to it =P - super sexay

Answer (score 3):

Other than the fact that how you expect the output to be (0, 3, 7, 11, 15) when that clearly isn't increments of 4 (0 + 4 != 3), you can use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i+=4) {
    alert(i);
}
```